# Set Attribute With Same Name As Databse Field in Laravel returns Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, attributes

I have a problem in my Project. I have  a field Name contact_number where I stored json data in this format `{"code":"","number":""}`. I want to set Two Attribute name `getCountryCodeAttribute` and `getContactNumberAttribute` so that I can access `code` and `number` individually. But it Throws error

```
Undefined property: App\Models\Profile::$contact_number
```

My Model Code Is

```
?php

namespace App\Models;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'contact_number' => 'array',
    ];

    public function getCountryCodeAttribute()
    {
        $contact_number = $this->contact_number;
        return $contact_number['code'];
    }

    public function getContactNumberAttribute()
    {
        $contact_number = $this->contact_number;
        return $contact_number['number'];
    }

}
```

I don't know how to solve this. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is it just a CP failure or is your model missing the import for `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `accessor` you can not access the property. So it's `Undefined`

```php
    public function getContactNumberAttribute()
    {
        $contact_number = $this->contact_number;//$this->contact_number is not valid
        return $contact_number['number'];
    }
```

change `ContactNumber` part to something else like `PhoneNumber`

```php
    public function getCountryCodeAttribute()
    {
        $contact_number = $this->contact_number;

        return $contact_number['code'];
    }

    public function getPhoneNumberAttribute()
    {
        $contact_number = $this->contact_number;

        return $contact_number['number'];
    }
```

and then access it like this.

```php
    dd(User::find(1)->phone_number);
    dd(User::find(1)->country_code);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You already have a field named `contact_number`, but you want to defined a attribute contract_number, this is a mistake, try to use another name.
2. Your `contract_number` is an json format. After you take it out from database, it need to be decoded, or it will be string, so you cannot  use `$contact_number['number']` too.

```php
public function getProfileContractCodeAttribute()
{
    $contact_number = json_decode($this->contact_number, true);
    return $contact_number['code'];
}

public function getProfileContractNumberAttribute()
{
    $contact_number = json_decode($this->contact_number, true);
    return $contact_number['number'];
}
```

so you can get attribute like this:

```php
Profile::find(1)->profile_contract_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with `json_decode`

```
public function getCountryCodeAttribute()
{
    $contact_number = json_decode($this->contact_number);
    return $contact_number['code'];
}

public function getContactNumberAttribute()
{
    $contact_number = json_decode($this->contact_number);
    return $contact_number['number'];
}
```